# POIXMLDocumentPart getRelations() undefined

Tags: java, xwpf

I have taken the code for getting pictures of `.docx` file from the link https://code.google.com/p/zkpoi/source/browse/branches/zkpoi/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.java?r=34

But I get error for

> for (POIXMLDocumentPart poixmlDocumentPart : getRelations()) that getRelations() is undefined.

```
public List<XWPFPictureData> getAllPictures()
{
    List<XWPFPictureData> pictures;
    if (pictures == null)
    {
        pictures = new ArrayList<XWPFPictureData>();
        for (POIXMLDocumentPart poixmlDocumentPart : getRelations())
        {
            if (poixmlDocumentPart instanceof XWPFPictureData)
            {
                pictures.add((XWPFPictureData) poixmlDocumentPart);
            }
        }
    }
    return pictures;
}
```

I use `poi-3.9 jar` and `po-ooxml-3.9 jar` . Please help me to rectify the error. I taken this code snippet to remove pictures of `.docx` file using `xwpfdocument` java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. Fix applied given below.

1. Extend the `POIXMLDocument`
2. Add constructor
3. Override the method `getAllEmbedds()`
   Exactly same as given in the link.